# "Unexpected synthetic property @transitionMessages found" error in angular 17 when trying to test a component with a dropdown from angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular17

My application runs fine. My application is a standalone component app. When I try to test the component, I get the error mentioned in the title in Karma.

Imports of my component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { NavigationComponent } from '../../../0_navigation/navigation.component';
import jsonDataShipments from '../../../../../assets/shipments.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sort-functionality',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NavigationComponent, MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule],
  templateUrl: './sort-functionality.component.html',
  styleUrl: './sort-functionality.component.css'
})
```

Config of my app

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(), provideAnimationsAsync(),
  ],
};
```

Error

```
Error: NG05105: Unexpected synthetic property @transitionMessages found. Please make sure that:
  - Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.
  - There is corresponding configuration for the animation named `@transitionMessages` defined in the `animations` field of the `@Component` decorator (see https://angular.io/api/core/Component#animations).
```

If I import `BrowserAnimationsModule`

I get this error

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted the code of the test rather than the app. The issue likely lies in the way the test is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try importing BrowserAnimationsModule like this:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

And import it into your testfile like this:

```
imports: [YourComponentName, BrowserAnimationsModule]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

BrowserAnimationsModule should only be loaded once in your app, in the root module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

"For NgModule based applications import BrowserAnimationsModule, which introduces the animation capabilities into your Angular root application module."

Documented here:
https://angular.io/guide/animations#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`provideAnimations`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/provideAnimations) instead of [`provideAnimationsAsync`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/async/provideAnimationsAsync)

On reading the documentation

> When you use this function(`provideAnimationsAsync`) instead of the eager `provideAnimations()`, animations won't be renderered until the renderer is loaded.

maybe this is why the issue happens!

Comment: If I change `provideAnimationsAsync` to `provideAnimations` I still get the same error when I run a test.